# Simple renaming my custom post type set with a plugin doesn't work?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development

I have created a plugin which activates a custom post type and it all works, but now i wanted to rename the custom post type, say "future-visitors" in stead of "past-visitors".

But when i just replace within my class

```
public function cpt_visitors() {
.........
    register_post_type('past-visitors', $args);
```

for

```
public function cpt_visitors() {
```

........
        register_post_type('future-visitors-2016', $args);

The custom post type is not shown in the administration section.

And i have replace each reference to past-visitors with future-visitors? 
With my second attempt i have tested with first defining a constant like

```
define('CPT_POST_TYPE', 'future-visitors-2016');
```

and replaced eacht reference to past-visitors with CPT_POST_TYPE

What did i overlooked? Any caching issues?

regards

Comment: The post type for each post  is hardcoded in the `post_type` field of the `wp_posts` table.

Comment: hmm, ok what i found out you can't seem to use double - - as your custom post-type so i changed it  to `future-visitors2016`